# Can we multiply cardinalities

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given sets $A$ and $B$, is their an appropriate notion of the product
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\card}{card}\card(A)\card(B)$$
of their cardinalities, which gives the standard product of natural numbers when $A$ and $B$ are finite? We would like $\card(A)\card(B)$ to be again a cardinal number.

Comment: How about $\mathrm{card}(A\times B)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_multiplication ?

Answer (score 2):

As Spenser and Simpler Art have commented, the standard would be the cardinality of the Cartesian product:

$\mathrm{card}(A)\mathrm{card}(B) := \mathrm{card}(A \times B)$

This would behave 'naturally' in ZFC as you suggested.

Note that in set theory the result of Cartesian would be ordered pairs, often defined by the kuratowski definition:

$\langle x,y \rangle := \{ \{x\} , \{x,y\} \}$